# IntelliJ IDE Não encontra JDK

Tags: intellij-idea, jdk

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele ja entra com um diretorio padrão do java em /usr/lib/jvm/

mas não consegue encontrar o jdk em nenhuma pasta dentro deste diretorio

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, e vi na imagem, essa pasta contem o JRE e não JDK. Qual distro você está usando?

Comment: Linux version 3.19.0-56-generic (buildd@lgw01-10) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:03:15 UTC 2016

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ir em file>project structure e adicionar manualmente um JDK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui